# Error class message creation way

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I need to create message class that can retrieve the data for message and print it out the problem is that I must provide in the message class to the static filed value like (public static String exc01 ="testErr";) if I remove the equal `"testErr"`; Im getting an error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.handleGetObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(Unknown Source)
    at test1.Messages.getString(Messages.java:19)
    at test1.TestMessageClass.main(TestMessageClass.java:8)
```

1.why should I provide value to the static string exc01 in class message if the message properties file already contain the error value?

2.there is better/nicer to do this all logic of messages ?

for that I have created message class as follows

```
package msg;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Messages {
    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "test1.messages"; 
    private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    public static String exc01 ="testErr";
    public static String exc02; 

    private Messages() {
    }

    public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            return RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }
}
```

I have file for message under the same package which is called messages.properties and contain the following message

```
exc01=Failed to create the extension for {0}
exc02=Failed to create the extension
```

I have created simple test program

```
public class TestMessageClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Messages.getString("exc01"));
        System.out.println(Messages.getString(Messages.exc01));
    }
}
```

print

Failed to create the extension for {0}
!testErr!

Comment: What's the question exactly? Do you want to know the reason for the NullPointerException?

Comment: no ,why should I put the equal "testErr" if in the message properties file I already have the value for the message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls

```
Messages.getString(Messages.exc01)
```

`Messages.exc01` is a variable or type String. Its default value is null. It's not "exc01" as you seem to believe. You're confusing the name of a variable with its value.

So, if you don't initialize the variable, the code above tries to get the message from the properties file having a null key, which doesn't make sense: you must provide a non-null key, and that's why you get a NullPointerException.

If you want to get the message for the key "exc01", then you can use

```
Messages.getString("exc01")
```

or you can initialize any String variable to "exc01", and pass this variable:

```
public static String exc01 = "exc01";
...
Messages.getString(Messages.exc01);
```

Note that exc01 should be defined as a constant, and not as a variable. It should thus be final, and respect the Java naming conventions for constants:

```
public static final String EXC01 = "exc01";
...
Messages.getString(Messages.EXC01);
```

Note that if you initialize the variable with "testErr", as you did, the code will look for the message associated with the key "testErr" in the properties file. And since such a message doesn't exist, you'll get a MissingResourceException, and the ctach block will thus return `!testErr!`. That's why you have `!testErr!` in your test output.